# Cordovas's ChildBrowser in IOS doesn't display the "open in" extras when viewing PDF file

Tags: ios, pdf, cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

The ChildBrowser PhoneGap plugin uses a WebView on top of our main application in order to display external urls. There are numerous posts about showing a local PDF file through ChildBrowser. Therefore I am able to view local PDF files through ChildBrowser. So far so good.

My question is, I have noticed that in Safari when viewing a PDF, it has an "on tap event" that displays the feature "open in" which enables the user to interact with the PDF file in another way.
If the ChildBrowser is a WebView, how can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by writing some native code.
Added a new button in the ChildBrowser.xib file and some custom implementation.

Comment: Is there anyway that you could share this information to the community? I want to do this as well with my phonegap app but since i do not know objectiv-c, I am at a loss